# is there a way to view via code the iphone sms archive?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is there a way to view via code the iphone sms archive and sort them in an app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would imagine that on a jailbroken phone you could read the DB, but using the normal SDK this is impossible. Each app is sandboxed to prevent it from reading data from other apps. Also, there is no API for it.

Answer (score 1):

In short - no, SDK does not provide access to this information.

Answer (score 0):

If it's jailbroken most certainly, you can even edit it by hand!